# How can tiny black holes exist?

Tags: black-holes, matter

If Black Holes are a function of mass being crushed, how can black holes be theoretically formed in particle accelerators?

Comment: Black holes aren't formed in particle accelerators, as far as we know. I also don't understand how the first part of your sentence links logically to the second part.

Answer (score 2):

The lifetime of a black hole depends on [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation). The evaporation gives a [lifetime which is estimated to be proportional to a power of the black hole mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#Black_hole_evaporation). The smaller the mass the higher the evaporation and the smaller the lifetime.

A [black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) is predicted from general relativity, and modeled as a singularity when gravitational attraction compacts energy beyond the horizon. Some general relativity models allow also for small masses forming singularities called [micro black holes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole)

> It is possible that such quantum primordial black holes were created in the high-density environment of the early Universe (or big bang), or possibly through subsequent phase transitions. They might be observed by astrophysicists through the particles they are expected to emit by Hawking radiation.
>
> Some hypotheses involving additional space dimensions predict that micro black holes could be formed at energies as low as the TeV range, which are available in particle accelerators such as the Large Hadron Collider.

These are searched for at LHC experiments because they are expected to decay thermodynamically very fast, a different behavior to particle resonances. See [this report f](http://cds.cern.ch/record/1358779/files/EPS-HEP%202009_245.pdf)or some details.

> 5. Search for micro black holes
>
> If microscopic black holes are produced at the LHC, they should undergo Hawking evaporation: particle pairs produced by vacuum fluctuations may be split, with one particle falling into the black hole and the other projected outward. This gives a very distinct signature...